# HTML div floating background issue

Tags: html, css

say for example i have 2 div in a div like this

```
<div style="width: 300px; backround-color: #000000;">
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 150px; float: left; background-color: #00ff00; color: #ffffff;">This is left</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 150px; background-color: #ff0000; color: ##ffffff;">This is right</div>
</div>
```

Now my question is why i cant see my background black color below ref if green div is 300 pixels in height.

Comment: No-repro in Chromium 17, running on Ubuntu 11.04: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K9Qye/1/ (edited to update the link and correct the spelling mistake spotted by Brian Hoover, which I [originally missed](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K9Qye).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text flow is "killed" if you use `float: ...;`

What you can do is to say where the text flow should be after the elements with the float attribute with the "clear" attribute.

You can do:

```
<div style="width: 300px; backround-color: #000000;">
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 150px; float: left; background-color: #00ff00; color: #ffffff;">This is left</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 150px; background-color: #ff0000; color: ##ffffff;">This is right</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: It's simple. If you define where the text-flow should be after the to div-elements, the div-elements above are seen as text and the background will be visible. (Sorry, very hard to explain in english)

Answer (score 3):

DIVs don't handle the height of embedded floated divs very well.  You can solve this problem a couple of ways.  The easiest is to put a clear:both div just before the end of the outside div.

```
<div style="width: 300px; background-color: #000000;">
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 150px; float: left; background-color: #00ff00; color: #ffffff;">This is left</div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 150px; background-color: #ff0000; color: ##ffffff;">This is right</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

It also helps to spell background-color right :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clear, I found that I could add

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the containing div's css.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you don't define the wrapping divs height. To see the background from it you need to have it bigger than the div inside.

Also remove one of the # in `color: ##ffffff;"`.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hustlerinc/RFNFh/) of your problem, define the parent divs height and you will see the black come out under the other 2 divs.

Comment: Thats not right. You don't have to define a height for the parent element in order to see the background.

Comment: If there is another color in the child div yes you do, padding or margin can do it aswell, but if they are the exact size the child div blocks the parent div... He has green and red in his child divs. read the code.

Comment: <div style"clear: both;"></div> will work better, because you don't have to define the height (maybe it will change and than it's not going to work, ...). In the code only the first childNode has the height 150px, the other one has no height defined. So the childnodes won't have the exact size.

Comment: @user1150525 you're right, you cannot decide parent element height, say fr xample you are posting 10 boxes and the parent element is a background, you cannot pre-define its height.

Comment: @user1150525 did you see he has floats? clear:both would not put them next to eachother, and it destroys his style.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It will! clear: both; just says: this will be below the tags above.

Comment: There's not a question to debate, he gave a perfect solution, it does preserves my floats, positions, simple it stretches my background color all the way down of the parent element which I was asking for. Perfect solution.